# Can't get most basic DataBinding to work with a <DataTemplate><ViewCell><local:MyCustomView Param={Binding .}> in a ListView, but Items kindof load

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding, maui

### Description

Here is the result I'm getting:

[image: Unstyled-looking ListView rendered in my .NET MAUI app]

**KCellSetupPage.xaml**

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:KCellSetupViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
           EventName="Appearing"
           Command="{Binding GetContentCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <RefreshView Command="{Binding GetContentCommand}"
                    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}">

                <ListView x:Name="CommandListView"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCommand}"
                            SelectionMode="Single">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <local:ModbusCommandView Command="{Binding .}" x:DataType="models:ModbusCommand" />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>             
                        
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    
                </ListView>
            </RefreshView>
```

So it looks pretty crappy, the default styling - what happened to the usual ListView, fat boarder-boxes?

So I think this is a Binding issue, because it comes with these:

[image: Binding Errors]

```
Severity    Count   Data Context    Binding Path    Target  Target Type Description File    Line    Project
Error   2   KCellSetupViewModel .   ModbusCommandView.Command   ModbusCommand   'MyProject.ViewModels.KCellSetupViewModel' cannot be converted to type 'MyProject.Models.ModbusCommand' C:\Users\fruit\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\[....]\Views\KCellSetupPage.xaml   38  MyProject
```

### Question

So my question is, why can't I bind to the ModbusCommand objects indidually in the ListView's ItemSource naturally with {Binding .}?  Next question is, what should I put there instead of {Binding .}?

Thanks.

### What I've Tried

`{Binding Source={Relative Source .}}`   -- Was expecting something to be fixed, but the error was essentially the same thing - Binding Errors.
`{Binding Source={x:Reference .}}` -- I don't know what I'm doing here by now and there's no good reference on the subject.

I just thought of a hackfix: since I can successfully bind to the Item's (ModbusCommand typed) members such as Description (which is what is pictured), then maybe I could just put a public property of type ModbusCommand called "This" and it returns the this reference in C#.

Please guide me in the .NET MAUI Data-binding world !

Comment: what about your binding isn't actually working?

Comment: There are Binding Errors, from this one change, I can't just be creating an app full of them.  Even though Description works, something is bound to fail.  {Binding .} is referring to the page's ViewModel (the page holds the ListView which holds what I thought "." would point to a list item of type ModbusCommand).   And it's suspicious that I have these binding errors while the styling went to shit.

Comment: I've also tried {Binding} and have read through the Binding extensions such as x:Static's documenation.

Comment: The binding message is usually due to a missing DataType, which you have.  You might try moving it to the DataTemplate.

Comment: @Jason, I've currently tried every possible permuation including this one showing everything:
`
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ModbusCommand">
                            <ViewCell BindingContext="{Binding ThisObject}" x:DataType="models:ModbusCommand">
                                <local:ModbusCommandView Command="{Binding ThisObject}" x:DataType="models:ModbusCommand"/>
                            </ViewCell>`

No matter what I put, it won't shake the fact that the ListView is giving me the Page's instance

Comment: What is the type of `Commands`?

Comment: @Jason: public ObservableCollection<ModbusCommand> Commands { get; } = new();

Comment: Found out this was seen by others.  They said just ignore errors.  Others said switch to CollectionView, but when I do that I get the error that absolutely nothing appears to show up (maybe Null everywhere)?

Comment: Are you using ViewCell?  CollectionView does not support that

Comment: That may relate to [Compiled Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0). You could see the example here: [Use compiled bindings in a DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0#use-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate)